# Manually building a collection in BluePrism

Tags: collections, insert, blueprism, rpa

I would like to collect status information of my RPA process in a collection, so each time I need to add a new steatus, I should create a new row and make it active, but the Business Object `Utility - Collection Manipulation` does not support that. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add more detail? You want to collect information about a running process... within the running process? Or another process running on a different session?

Comment: Within the running process.(But that is not essential. The question is about building a collection from scratch.)

Answer (score 1):

This action is not in the `Utility - Collection Manipulation` Business Object, 
but in the built in `Collection` Business object
and the action is simply called `Add Row`.